# Using char_length in a selection function that equals everything BUT a particular number

Tags: arcpy

I am selecting records with a character length greater than 13 and then again with a character length les than 11.  I'd like to do these in a single select if possible.

How can I combine the selection queries below into a single SelectLayerByAttribute, rather than having it in two selections?

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION",  "CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) > 13")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "ADD_SELECTION",  "CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) < 11")
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: This works when I run it in Arcpy, I was just wondering if there was another way to phrase it within one selection.

Comment: So you want to know *how* to write the query, rather than if it's possible?  Please [edit] your question to make that clear.  Put your specific question in the body of your question, then update the title with something more concise

Comment: An "is it possible" question can usually be answered with a "Yes it's possible" or a "No it isn't possible".  If you want to know if something is possible, then make an attempt at doing it and see what happens.  If you actually want to know *how* to do something, then you need to ask "How do I..."

Comment: I have updated your question - please check that this is what you want, and [edit] if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways that might work

First I'd attempt to check if a the Char_Length isn't `12`

```
"CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) != 12"
```

If this doesn't work I'd attempt putting the two together

```
"CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) >= 13 OR CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) <= 11")
```

Note I've put `>= 13` and `<= 11` to find lengths including 13 and 11.  If you want to exclude these, then remove the `=` as necessary.